# How do i get specific columns from a thenInclude using .net-core and Entity Framework Core and Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have been trying to make this query work for some time but i just cant seem to achieve that, the problem is i cant return only those columns i want

```
var thread = context.threads.Include(t => t.posts).ThenInclude(p => p.ApplicationUser).Include(t => t.ApplicationUser).Include(t => t.movie).Where(t => t.Id == id)
```

The query returns all the information of the ApplicationUser including the email and hashed Password and of course i don't want that i tried doing this

```
var thread = context.threads.Include(t => t.posts).ThenInclude(p => p.ApplicationUser).Include(t => t.ApplicationUser).Include(t => t.movie).Where(t => t.Id == id).Select(t => new
            {
                title = t.title,
                body = t.body,
                threadUserName = t.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                postsThread = t.posts
            });
```

But i Hit a roadblock when i have to query the UserName of the posts so data from the ThenInclude, tried doing something like `t.posts.ApplicationUser.UserName` and similar but it didnt work, how do i query the username of the posts?
The ApplicationUser is a class deriving from the IdentityUser class in the Identity net-core package.

Comment: did you face any error, What exactly didn't work?

Comment: Well i get an error when trying to do `.posts.ApplicationUser` that posts dosn't contain Application User even tho it has a `public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For querying `postsThread`, you could add a new `Select`, something like:

```
var thread = _appDbContext.Threads
                          .Include(t => t.Posts)
                          .ThenInclude(p => p.ApplicationUser)
                          .Include(t => t.ApplicationUser)
                          .Where(t => t.Id == id)
                          .Select(t => new
                                       {
                                            title = t.Title,
                                            body = t.Body,
                                            threadUserName = t.ApplicationUser.UserName,
                                            postsThread = t.Posts.Select(p => new {
                                                                                      p.Content,
                                                                                      p.ApplicationUser.UserName
                                                                                  })
                                       })
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Please can you help me understand how the keywords `t`, `p`, are evaluated. I'm new to EF.